# Ruby continuously reading from beginning of file

Tags: ruby

How am I able to read a text file in ruby from the beginning (first line) of the file?

For example this code:

```
while line = file.gets
[code here]
end
```

reads from the first line to the last line and STOPS.

BUT, I would like to start again from the first line, and scan all the way to the last line.

Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to read infinitely the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have written is quite unusual in Ruby programming, most of the time a file is read line by line using [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) methods, for example:

```
file.each { |line| [code here] }
```

That said you could use the [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) method to read the file more than one time. Given the following file, say `foo.txt`:

```
foo
bar
```

You can read it two times using the following code:

```
open('foo.txt') do |file|
  file.cycle(2) { |line| puts line }      
end

# Output:
#
# foo
# bar
# foo
# bar
```

If you pass `nil`, or no argument, to `cycle` it will read the file forever.

Comment: Ruby seems to have some method for just about any single thing one wants to do; I'm always finding out about new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use `file.rewind` to revert it to the beginning.

Comment: Apologies @sawa, I removed my comment.

Comment: @mbratch Thanks. I am not particularly feeling bad. I just didn't want people to think I copied it.